# Prevent User from editing list item from UI in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have requirement to prevent users from editing a list item through UI.
I want to edit item only through programmatic way.
I want to prevent them from editing items from default edit page of the list.
Any suggestion are grateful...

Comment: Did you try to remove permission from the list?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint permissions will even stop the user from editing the items programatically. (unless runwithelevatedprivileges is used). Another solution would be to hide [edit item] option using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with SharePoint permissions.

Navigate to Site Actions > Site Permissions and select the user (they might be part of a SharePoint group, so check inside them too). Check the check box next to the user name and select Edit User Permissions from the ribbon. Then ensure that View Only and Read check boxes are checked for that specific user.

Hope this helps!